# Agrupar array en objetos con propiedades personalizadas

Tags: javascript, array, map, ecmascript-6, reducer

buenas tardes a todos, tengo el siguiente arreglo:

```
const aDatos = [
  { v: 1 },
  { v: 2 },
  null,
  { v: 3 },
  { v: 4 },
  { v: 5 },
  null,
  { v: 6 },
  { v: 7 },
  { v: 8 },
  { v: 9 },
  { v: 10},
];

const encabezados = ["data1", "data2", "data3", "data4"];
```

y quiero agrupar los datos con propiedades personalizadas, los que vienen en el segundo arreglo (encabezados) de tal manera que quede así:

```
[
  {
    data1: { v: 1 },
    data2: { v: 2 },
    data3: null,
    data4: { v: 3 },
  },
  {
    data1: { v: 4 },
    data2: { v: 5 },
    data3: null,
    data4: { v: 6 },
  },
  {
    data1: { v: 7 },
    data2: { v: 8 },
    data3: { v: 9 },
    data4: { v: 10},
  },
]
```

estoy intentando de esta manera pero no me queda como lo pretendo.

```
const o = datta.map(function (e) {
var obj = {};

keys.forEach(function (key) {
    obj[key] = e;
});

return obj;
```

});

De antemano, agradezco las sugerencias que me puedan brindar para poder resolver el problema.

Saludos

Answer (score 1, accepted):

podrías intentar algo así..

**Versión 1**

```
const aDatos = [
  { v: 1 },
  { v: 2 },
  null,
  { v: 3 },
  { v: 4 },
  { v: 5 },
  null,
  { v: 6 },
  { v: 7 },
  { v: 8 },
  { v: 9 },
  { v: 10 },
];

const encabezados = ["data1", "data2", "data3", "data4"];
const arrayFinal = [];
let aDatosIndex = 0;

while (arrayFinal.length < aDatos.length / encabezados.length) {
  const objTemporal = {};

  for (let i = 0; i < encabezados.length; i++) {
    objTemporal[encabezados[i]] = aDatos[aDatosIndex];
    aDatosIndex++;
  }
  arrayFinal.push(objTemporal);
}

console.log(arrayFinal);
```

**Versión 2**

```
const aDatos = [
  { v: 1 },
  { v: 2 },
  null,
  { v: 3 },
  { v: 4 },
  { v: 5 },
  null,
  { v: 6 },
  { v: 7 },
  { v: 8 },
  { v: 9 },
  { v: 10 },
];

const encabezados = ["data1", "data2", "data3", "data4"];
const arrayFinal = [];

while (aDatos.length > 0) {
  const objTemporal = {};
  for (let i = 0; i < encabezados.length; i++) {
    objTemporal[encabezados[i]] = aDatos[i];
  }
  arrayFinal.push(objTemporal);
  aDatos.splice(0, encabezados.length);
}

console.log(arrayFinal);
```